# please while loop breaking after one row, is it the assignment operator

Tags: php

Please help me, my while loop seems to break after the first loop as $totalprice is only echoed once. What could be the cause?

```
$pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)) 
   //echo $row['Pquantity'] * $row['Price'];
  $totalprice = $row['Price'] * $row['Pquantity'];
  echo "$totalprice";
```

Comment: Wat? Please rewrite your question so that it makes at least some sense.

Comment: Eh? Are you saying that this loop only executes once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)) 
  {
 //echo $row['Pquantity'] * $row['Price'];
  $totalprice += $row['Price'] * $row['Pquantity'];
}
  echo "$totalprice";
```

Comment: thanks, that actually killed it @ Vytautas  and @ Akhil Thayyil,

Comment: but ow do i make it echo each induvidual multiplication so as to verifify the result, because at the moment it adds up the mulplication

Comment: $pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)) 
  {
 echo $row['Pquantity'] * $row['Price'];//Prints result each time
  $totalprice += $row['Price'] * $row['Pquantity'];//Adds result to total
}
  echo "$totalprice";

Comment: really grate full @ Vytautas and @ Akhil Thayyil

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$totalprice += $row['Price'] * $row['Pquantity'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is running fine,  you just forgot to add curly bracers.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)) {
  $totalprice = $row['Price'] * $row['Pquantity'];
  echo "$totalprice";
}
```

Without the bracers just the first line of code after the head of your loop is ecexuted and you will see only the last result of your calculation echoed.

Comment: thanks @ yan.kun
@ Udhay all fine

Answer (score 0):

The result may have only one record. To check that please check the number of rows by `echo mysql_num_rows($pplresult);` and confirm that you are having more than one row in your result set